# Problem at start the server in the background with Symfony console

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

I update Symfony console to v4.12.0 . Now when I start the server in the background with Symfony console by `symfony server:start -d` this error display:

> |ERROR| SERVER Impossible to go to the background error="Could not
>   watch status file: The parameter is incorrect."

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the 4.12.0 version. Downgrading to 4.11.0 fixed that for me. See also https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/188

Edit: v4.12.1 fixes the problem according to the issue linked above.

Comment: symfony self:rollback restores the previous version